# Detailed rules when о (=about) becomes об or обо?

Tags: словоупотребление, предлоги

I have gathered from various sites/resources, the following rules concerning the preposition “**o**” which, when its meaning is “**about**”, is always followed by the prepositional case (предложный падеж):

**1**. before any hard vowel (а, и, о, у, э), always use **"об"**;

**2**. before any consonant or any soft vowel (е, я, ю), always use **"о"**;

**3**. **"обо"** would be only used in the following 6 expressions: -

- **обо мне** : about me;
- **обо всех**: about everybody (pronoun);
- **обо всём**: about everything (pronoun) or about the whole of something (i.e. masculine and neuter adjectives);
- **обо всей**: about the whole of something, i.e. the feminine adjective;
- **обо что-то** : about something;
- **обо всяком/всякой/всяких…** : about any of something, i.e. the masc.+neuter/feminine/plural adjective.

**4**. **Exceptions**: when **“о”** does not mean “about” but **“against”**, it is then followed by the accusative case, and there are a limited number of exceptions to the above rules, e.g. **об пол** (against the ground), **об руку** (against the arm), **об стену** (against the wall) – in all these three cases, **об** goes in front of a consonant so rule 2 is not respected. To be noted that in this meaning, we could also find accusative constructions such as **обо всего …**, **обо весь …**, **обо всё …**, **обо всю …**, **обо всех …**, and **обо все…** corresponding respectiveley to masc. animated, masc. unanimated, neuter, feminine, plural animated and plural unanimated.

**My question is twofold :**

**a)**  are the above rules really **exhaustive and contemplating all possible cases**, especially the third one, or could we think of other situations where обо would be used?

**b)**  are the 3 exceptions mentioned under 4, when “о/об” means “against”, **the only 3 exceptions to rules 1 to 3** or are there other cases where об could be used before a consonant when meaning “against” ? For example, should we say for “against the cupboard”: **о шкаф** or **об шкаф** ?

Thank you

Comment: **Обо что-то** is accusative and should go under 4.

Comment: Thank you @Sergey Slepov, so does обо что-то mean against something ? Would it require after it or could it just stand on its own ? Thank you again

Comment: What is "hard vowel" and in what sense и is hard?

Comment: I would say "об что-то" but "обо что".

Comment: обо всего and обо все (not ё) are wrong.

Comment: Also just look at difference as same as ‘a’ and ‘an’ before word starting with vowel, for example in ‘an elephant’. Same for обо, but for words starting with consonant.

Answer (score 3):

The prepositions **o, oб , обо** take the prepositional and accusative cases.

**Обо** is used with pronouns in the accusative: **обо что(что--нибудь что-то, что-либо)**,

with the prepositional :**обо мне**,

With both the accusative and the prepositional:**(весь) обо всё, обо всём, обо всю, обо всей, обо все, обо всех**.

With the prepositional case, we use **o** before a consonant, **об** before a vowel.

**О папе, юле, ели, яблоке. Об Азии, улице, отце, иголке, эпохе**.

With the accusative, we use **об** before a vowel:

**Об арку, угол, эстакаду, иголку**.

And before consonants, we use either **o or об**.

**О стену, об стену, о забор, об забор, о тротуар, об тротуар,о шкаф, об шкаф**(to be continued)

To remember: **о нём, о ней, о них, об него, об неё, об них**.

And idioms should be memorized: **рука об руку**

The source is Орфоэпический словарь русского языка под ред. Аванесова.

Answer (score 1):

I have some additional notes on "обо". There are several mistakes/typos in your initial lists, and I would like to sum them up with examples.

There are two cases in which "обо" is used:

1. with the meaning "about" (prepositional case)
2. with the meaning "against"/"upon" (accusative case)

In both cases, the form "обо" represents an exception, so there's only a limited number of expressions where it can be used. Let's break it down:

**1. "обо" = about** (prepositional case)

- обо мне (about me)
- обо всех (about everyone)
- обо всём (about everything, from original "всё")
- обо всём X (about the whole X, from original "весь")
- обо всей X (about the whole X, from original "вся" - the feminine of "весь")

*** additionally, it's possible to use it with "всякие" (various) or "многие" (many), but I would prefer "о всяких", "о многих".

**2. "обо" = against / upon** (accusative case)

- обо что? (against what?)
- обо что-то (against something)
- обо всё (against everything)

*** the following two are rare, both of them are usually used with "о" instead:

- обо всего X (against the whole X, from original "весь", **only used for animated objects**)
- обо всю X (against/upon the whole X, from original "вся")

Please note that all the other examples in your "обо"-lists are incorrect! You can't say "обо весь", "обо все", and some of the other examples you listed are just mixed up between the cases.

FYI: when "обо" is used in the meaning "against/upon" there are very few verbs that can be used with it:

- удариться обо что-то (to hit oneself against something, run against something)

> Обо что ты ударился?

- споткнуться обо что-то (to trip over something)

> Я обо что-то споткнулась.

- испачкаться обо что-то (to get dirty with something)

> Я испачкалась обо всё это дерьмо. (sorry, couldn't think of another example)

- вытереть обо что-то (to wipe with something) or обтереться обо что-то (to rub against something)

> Он обтёрся обо всего кота. (the whole situation is a bit weird, but I can't think of a normal case in which "обо всего" would be used naturally)

- точить обо что-то (to sharpen with something)

> Кошка успела поточить когти обо всю мою мебель.

... and maybe some other verbs that I couldn't think of.

And one more thing: above, I listed "обо всего" which, as I mentioned, only works with animated objects. If you need more information on the difference between accusative forms for masculine animate and inanimate objects, here's a link: https://www.ruspeach.com/learning/5109/

As for the difference between "о"/"об", I agree with the previous comment, but there are several more examples I can add to the second "об"-list (accusative case). With the verbs like "вытереть" or "удариться" I would normally use "об" with these pronouns:

- об меня (against/upon me)
- об тебя (against/upon you)
- об себя (against/upon oneself)
- об неё (against/upon her)
- об него (against/upon him)

With other pronouns and nouns starting with consonants, you can usually choose between "о"/"об" ("Ударился об шкаф"/"Ударился о шкаф" and "Вытер об нас ноги"/"Вытер о нас ноги" all sound correct to me). I tend to use "об" in most cases to emphasize the difference from "о" with the meaning "about".

Comment: Another excellent answer! You must live in an English-speaking country, no?

Comment: No.... It's a bit awkward to say it, but I live in Russia

Comment: HOW DO YOU WRITE THIS KIND OF ENGLISH???

Comment: Probably all those years of watching British crime dramas finally bore fruit... haha

Comment: Well it's outstanding. No Runglish. And it reads more American than anything. As a professional editor, I'm very impressed. I have a Telegram with a handful of other Russians with your level of English, if you're interested. Mostly question about the finer points of English/Russian, memes, jokes, and we meet occasionally on Zoom to read from books. I think you'd like it. Let me know.

Comment: American??? Must be Faulkner's influence... And please send me the link to your Telegram, I'd love to join!

Comment: I got it, thank you!